# maven assembly plugin : remove SNAPSHOT from dependency

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

The dependency jar added to the assembly zip has "`SNAPSHOT`" version added to its name. Is there a way to get only `version` number from `${artifact.baseVersion}` without `SNAPSHOT` ?

This is run inside `maven-assembly-plugin`. I would like the dependency to output like `parent-2.0.jar` instead of `parent-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

**assembly.xml**

```
<dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
            <includes>
                <include>www.example.com:parent:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT</include>
            </includes>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

Comment: If you make a release versions this will be done...but you have currently only a SNAPSHOT version so the result is a SNAPSHOT version...I would change the include not to use the version....

Comment: yes, but I cannot change that as we have only SNAPSHOT releases.

Comment: If you have `-SNAPSHOT` in your version you don't have releases at all only SNAPSHOT's...

Comment: sorry for my wrong use of jargon. yes it is SNAPSHOT only. But I want to hide the SNAPSHOT when packed using assembly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few methods of doing this depending on your pipeline. The maven versions plugin can be used,

http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html

http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#removeSnapshot

A configuration like this would do it,

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <newVersion>${project.version}</newVersion>
                    <allowSnapshots>false</allowSnapshots>              
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'd recommend wrapping it in a `profile` and activate it only when required. This will update the `project.version` with in the POM. You can then commit it back to the repo, leave it as is etc. etc.

You may also want to look at the build helper plugin which can handle regex-ing properties etc. if the versions plugin doesn't meet your needs.

http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html#

Comment: Does this work for the `dependency` artificats referred in assembly plugin? because I want to leave the project build version with `SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a simple solution. So I have added new property `${client-version}` and used it in assmebly.xml.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <client-version>2.0</client-version>
</properties>
```

**assembly.xml**

```
<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${client-version}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
```